# What does "turn the inner eye" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Dune (2021), during Bene Gesserit tests Paul's patience, Lady Jessica speaks to herself:

> Lady Jessica: I'll face my fear and I'll permit it to pass over me
> and through me. And when it has gone past...I will **turn the inner eye**
> and see its path.

What does "turn the inner eye" mean?

Comment: It's a science fiction story. The inner eye is a fictional sixth sense. It's not a real thing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "turning the inner eye" of a Bene Gesserit means little or nothing in English unless you're reading / watching Frank Herbert's *Dune*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the Frank Herbert quote -

> "I must not fear. Fear is the mind-killer. Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me. And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone there will be nothing. Only I will remain."

The inner eye, the mind's eye and the third eye are sometimes confused or interchanged. The general idea is either an ability to spiritually or supernaturally see something.

However, the third eye has more spiritual connotations as in Hindu beliefs or meditation where the third eye or 'brow chakra' is a doorway to higher consciousness.

The mind's eye is really another way of referring to thought, where to see something with your mind's eye is to actually think about it rather than physically see it.

The inner eye is another way of referring to both the above, or a different way of employing them. It is not such a well-known phrase, allowing more artistic licence.

I think in Frank Herbert's quote he is employing the term as an inner mental power akin to meditation where one of the goals is to think of nothing, and when a thought or image appears, watch it but not follow it. Allow it to appear, see where it goes and watch it disappear.

There is also a slight connection with a martial arts attitude, where the only thing to fear is fear itself, and by sinking into yourself and observing, rather than reacting, you can conquer fear, understand it and be free from it. In this way there is just you and your own mindfulness.

Comment: Aged 18, in 1970, I fell hard for a girl. While I was plucking up the courage to ask her out, she said she'd read an amazing novel, called _Dune_ by Frank Herbert. It was great, she said, and I ought to read it. I bought the paperback edition. After about three chapters, a problem arose. I found a growing desire to stop reading the damn thing. Not just for a while, but forever. I also felt my attachment to the girl waning.

Comment: @Michael Harvey
I had the same experience, unfortunately - minus the girl. I know it's a great novel, but I just could not get into it. It actually put me off sci-fi. I think it's often the way with 'classics'. I picked up Lord of the Rings and re-started at page one at least four times before I finally finished it. Love it now. The Hobbit however, I read in one day. Catcher in the Rye - could not see the point, put it down and never picked it up again. Not sure what that says about me.

Answer (score 1):

In context, I think Frank Herbert/Jessica mean self-reflection or self-examination: once her fear has passed, she will. metaphorically, observe the effect it had upon her and its lingering effects, as if her mind were a landscape she were looking at inwardly, through a different eye than she uses to look at the world around her. And she will learn something about herself from that.

This way of putting it sounds foreign or exotic.  It’s an effective way of conveying that Lady Jessica comes from a different culture and thinks in different metaphors.